# Proof that the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ is a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So let's pretend the phrase "commutator subgroup" wasn't mentioned, and that we're given that for some group $G$ we are defining $[G,G] := \lbrace ghg^{-1}h^{-1} | g,h \in G \rbrace$. Say we want to prove $[G,G] \leq G$. Google seems to evade me when searching for the proof, which makes me think it's very obvious, yet I can't see it...

The way I approached this was the following: we know that $[G,G]$ is non-empty since for $1 \in G$, $1 = 111^{-1}1^{-1} \Rightarrow 1 \in [G,G]$. Now, if $x,y \in [G,G]$, then it is sufficient to show that $xy^{-1} \in [G,G]$ to prove that it is a group. We have $x = aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ for some $a,b \in G$ and $y = cdc^{-1}d^{-1}$ for some $c,d \in G$. Observe,
$$xy^{-1} = (aba^{-1}b^{-1})(cdc^{-1}d^{-1})^{-1}$$
$$\Rightarrow xy^{-1} = (aba^{-1}b^{-1})(dcd^{-1}c^{-1})$$
I've played around with this expression to try to get it to look like $ghg^{-1}h^{-1}$, but to no avail. I figure I need to introduce products like $aa^{-1}, bb^{-1},$ etc in the right places, but it escapes me... Thoughts?

Comment: No the commutator subgroup is the subgroup generated by all the commutators, not only the commutator elements.

Comment: Huh so it seems like my problem here is that I don't understand what the commutator subgroup is... So do you mean we can write $[G,G] = <ghg^{-1}h^{-1} | g,h \in G>$? Meaning the fact that $xy^{-1}$ is in the set follows immediately?

Comment: @ImATurtle basically, yes. The point is the group generated by a set is always itself a group.

Comment: Let me just add that you wanted to prove that the product of two commutators is again a commutator (in general). As you are maybe convinced already this is not true. E.g. take the free group $F(a,b,c,d)$ and consider $[a,b] \cdot [c,d]$.